# Get output from functions which are run in parallel

Tags: python-3.x, function, python-multiprocessing

I have two functions which I am running asynchronously using python multiprocessing. I need to store values from each function in an array, to use it later.

I have tried to store the output in a numpy array in each of the functions and return them. However, I am not getting any output. The print statements are working alright.

```
x = np.array([])
y = np.array([])

def func1():
    for _ in range(1,150):
        print((rstr.xeger(random.choice(sList))))
        np.append(x,rstr.xeger(random.choice(sList)))
    return x

def func2():
    for _ in range(1,150):
        print(fake.name())
        np.append(y,fake.name())
    return y

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = multiprocessing.Pool(5)
    p2 = multiprocessing.Pool(5)
    print("Started")
    start = time.time()
    x = p1.apply_async(func1)
    y = p2.apply_async(func2)
    print(time.time() - start) 
    print("Ended")
```

I need the arrays x and y which are being returned from the two functions.

Comment: Are you passing any parameters to the functions ?

Comment: I think you are missing out passing a list for `apply_async` to make it multiprocessing for a list of parameters. If not please specify what exactly you want to do with the multiprocessing

Comment: @SundeepPidugu Each of the functions is generating a string in each iteration. I want to store this string in an array. For function 1, I need to store all the strings generated in an array (i.e, 1st index of array will store string generated in 1st iteration, 2nd index = 2nd iteration, etc). And then use this array elsewhere. Similarly for function 2. I want to process these two functions parallelly, store the strings generated in 2 different arrays and return them, to use them later.

Comment: @SundeepPidugu I am not passing any parameter.

Comment: So you want the loops inside the functions to be processed parallelly or just the functions?

Comment: @SundeepPidugu I need parallel processing to run the code faster. Running the loops parallelly will be faster or running the functions? Or what is the difference?